# Best way to extract the remainder of integer number

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

I know it is silly but I am wondering what is best way to get result like this:

```
223231 => 1
509048 => 8
348356 => 6
648353 => 3
```

Basically it will return the remainder from its nearest `'xxxx0'` value.

Any idea to use Math `(div, mode, bit operators...)` to accomplish this?

Comment: This is the moment, where you should take any book on C++ (C#?) of your choosing, and open the chapter on operators. Did you try using the modulo operator (`%`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just get the remainder when you divide the number by 10.

```
rem = number%10;

12345 % 10 = 5.
```

Comment: And the remainder is found using the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), as shown in your example.

Comment: Also note that prior to C++11 the remainder of a negative number was implementation defined as per section 5.6.4 in the standard. This has changed with C++11.

Comment: You are correct @molbdnilo, I have changed it thanks. :-)